# Как мгновенно поменять состояние Button, TextView и т.д.?

Tags: java, android

У меня не сложная программа но проблема заключается в этой части

```
Effects.highlightCorrectAnsware(key1,key2,key3,key4,correctKey,
                                upLeft,upRight,bottomLeft,bottomRight);                
try {
    Thread.sleep(2000);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.getMessage()
};
```

Функция highlight просто меняет цвета кнопок. Но почему наоборот, цвет меняется после 2 секундной паузы?

Я пробовал реализовывать с помощью другого потока, но это тоже не помогло. Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: в помощь https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/143-urok-80-handler-nemnogo-teorii-nagljadnyj-primer-ispolzovanija.html

Comment: спасибо но не помогло, у меня либо руки кривые, либо Handler не поможет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Команды, отрисовывающие интерфейс, при вызове не исполняются мгновенно, но попадают в очередь команд.

При этом они все работают в главном, UI потоке.

В итоге, когда вы усыпляете поток, то очередь команд, в которую вы добавили свою команду, зависает (вместе со всем интерфейсом) и начинает исполняться только по завершении сна потока.

Так делать нельзя, т.к. программа становится нерабочей. И даже, если UI поток зависнет более чем на 5 секунд, система выведет вам сообщение об этом и предложит закрыть программу.

Если вам надо изменить что-то в UI через n времени вам надо ждать в другом потоке, после чего вернуться в UI поток и вызвать команду изменения интерфейса. Это можно сделать через TimerTask, например или используя RxJava, что сложнее, но требует меньше кода.